# maximum number of namespaces supported by a Kubernetes cluster via k3s?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, kubernetes-namespace

How many maximum namespaces we can create in Kubernetes cluster via k3s.
I see Kubernetes Scalability thresholds here https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/sig-scalability/configs-and-limits/thresholds.md#kubernetes-thresholds, is there any difference in threshold for namespaces creation in case of k3s.

Answer (score 0):

As such there is no hard limit that you should have these many namespaces in a cluster. Namespace is a logical grouping of application/services and it doesn't consume any resources like cpu, memory or storage